# *The Theory of Nilpotent Groups* Definition 1.2

Tags: group-theory, definition

> Two subgroups $H$ and $K$ of a group $G$ are called *conjugate* if
> $g^{-1}Hg = K$ for some $g\in G$.
>
> **In particular, every normal subgroup of $G$ is conjugate to itself.**

Why does the bold remark only talk about normal subgroups? Non-normal subgroups of $G$ are also conjugate to themselves: take $g=1$.

Comment: You're right, of course; I think the intended meaning is that a normal subgroup is conjugate to itself via every $g \in G$.

Comment: It should perhaps read "... is conjugate *only* to itself".